# How to set the character of a string using a index in Swift

Tags: string, indexing, swift

(Sorry for my english)

In my app i need to set the value at a certain character in a string normaly i would be using:

```
var string = "This is a string"

var i = 3

string[i] = "a"
```

But in Swift i can't use the '[]' to select a character how can i do it in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the answer got a little longer, I wrote an extension on String to do the job

```
extension String {
    mutating func replaceCharacterAtIndex(index: Int, withString str: String) {
        replaceRange(Range(start: advance(self.startIndex, index), end: advance(self.startIndex, index+1)), with: str)
    }
}

var ab = "abcdefg"
ab.replaceCharacterAtIndex(3, withString: "o")
// ab now equals „abcodefg"
```

Note that replacing a Character in the String is no longer in O(1) but Tatget O(String.length) and can’t be because characters no longer have a fixed length in Swift (thanks, Swift)

Comment: It give me an error: use of unresolved identifier 'replaceRange'

Comment: Are you using the latest Beta? Because it compiles and works for me on Beta 7